# Quartz 2.x, How to get Trigger Type?

Tags: java, triggers, quartz

I am using quartz 2.x version.

I need get column `TRIGGER_TYPE` from `QRTZ_TRIGGERS` tables.

using API, how to get `TRIGGER_TYPE`?

This is my code:

```js
for (String group : scheduler.getTriggerGroupNames()) {
    for (TriggerKey triggerKey : scheduler.getTriggerKeys(GroupMatcher.<TriggerKey>groupEquals(group))) {
        Trigger trigger = scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey(triggerKey.getName(), triggerKey.getGroup()));
        System.out.println(scheduler.getSchedulerName());
        System.out.println(triggerKey.getName());
        System.out.println(triggerKey.getGroup());
        System.out.println(trigger.getJobKey());
        //job name
        //job group
        System.out.println(trigger.getDescription());
        System.out.println(trigger.getNextFireTime());
        System.out.println(trigger.getPreviousFireTime());
        System.out.println(trigger.getPriority());
        System.out.println(scheduler.getTriggerState(triggerKey(triggerKey.getName(), triggerKey.getGroup())));
        //trigger type
        System.out.println(trigger.getStartTime());
        System.out.println(trigger.getEndTime());
        System.out.println(trigger.getCalendarName());
        System.out.println(trigger.getMisfireInstruction());
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the Quartz documentation have to say about accessing TRIGGER_TYPE? Have you tried something like `SELECT TRIGGER_TYPE FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS`?

Comment: I would like to import it using the API instead of importing from db, but I can import other values into the API, but I can not find the API that gets TRIGGER_TYPE. Do you know?

Comment: improved grammar and formatting

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Trigger types, SimpleTrigger and CronTrigger.

Maybe look at their API. You will probably get clues there on how to distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 0):

The `TRIGGER_TYPE` information in the `QRTZ_TRIGGERS` is reflected at runtime in the specific Java type of the `Trigger` implementation:

- `CalendarIntervalTriggerImpl` -> `TTYPE_CAL_INT`,
- `CronTriggerImpl` -> `TTYPE_CRON`,
- `DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl` -> `TTYPE_DAILY_TIME_INT` and
- `SimpleTriggerImpl` -> `TTYPE_SIMPLE`.

There is also a default trigger type for custom `Trigger` types: `TTYPE_BLOB`.

Note that if you really want to access that information at runtime, you are better off using the following code:

```
TriggerPersistenceDelegate tDel = new StdJDBCDelegate().findTriggerPersistenceDelegate(trigger);

String type = TTYPE_BLOB;
if(tDel != null)
  type = tDel.getHandledTriggerTypeDiscriminator();
```